# How do I solve these two errors when creating a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm creating a simple trigger that will email me when a table is updated or inserted into:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
      WHERE name = 'sportsNewsUpd' AND type = 'TR')
   DROP TRIGGER sportsNewsUpd
GO

CREATE TRIGGER sportsNewsUpd
ON sportsNews
FOR Insert, UPDATE
AS
    EXEC master.webdb.xp_sendmail 
    @recipients = 'name@email.com',
    @subject = 'Sports News has been altered.'
GO
```

I am getting two errors:
Incorrect syntax near 'GO', 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first tatement in query batch., Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. (two 'GO', two errors).

My resources:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=sql.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (B. under examples)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189505.aspx

Comment: I'm using "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express"

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag to make it clear what RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

semicolon after    DROP TRIGGER sportsNewsUpd?

so...

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
  WHERE name = 'sportsNewsUpd' AND type = 'TR')
DROP TRIGGER sportsNewsUpd;
GO
```

Comment: semicolon after     EXEC master.webdb.xp_sendmail 
    @recipients = 'name@email.com',
    @subject = 'Sports News has been altered.'

Comment: I may have missunderstood. I removed the word 'GO' and added the semicolons and the two syntax errors went away. however the second error still exists

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects
          WHERE name = 'sportsNewsUpd' AND type = 'TR')
begin
    DROP TRIGGER sportsNewsUpd
end
GO  

CREATE TRIGGER sportsNewsUpd ON sportsNews FOR Insert, UPDATE AS 
    begin    
        EXEC master.webdb.xp_sendmail      
        @recipients = 'name@email.com',     
        @subject = 'Sports News has been altered.' 
    end 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you run the query(ies)?

I doubt very much that you would get these errors running the script from an SSMS query window. Also, you wouldn't get the errors if you were running it using `sqlcmd` or `osql`.

What I mean is I'm suspecting you are trying to run the script from the application and so you may have probably been unaware that [`GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) is not a part of T-SQL.

Solution in this case would be to split the script in two and run each part in turn.

Comment: paste the code into your SSMS window and click on the "parse" (checlmark) toolbar icon, you'll get the errors.

Comment: @RacerX: `Command(s) completed successfully`, says SSMS (SQL Server 2008 R2).